# Change color when a fixed div is above an other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a fullpage website with a simple structure.

```
<body>
<div class="menu">
    <li><a href="#01">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#02">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#03">Third</a></li>
</div>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div id="01" class="dark">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div id="02" class="light">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div id="03" class="dark">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
</body>


.menu{position: fixed; width:100%; color:white;}
.dark{background-color:black;}
.light{background-color:white;}
```

Each of my three pages are 100% height and width and I'm using the fullpage.js plugin for the scrolling. My #menu element is fixed so it don't move with the scrolling. I want to change the color of my menu depending on the background page so my text is always visible.

I could use jquery to check the active page and change my menu color, but I would like to do it like a mask. If I scroll down to place the separation line between two pages on my menu, I want the menu to be black on the white and white on the black. What I want to do is changing the color of my fixed div only where it's above an other div.

I tought about making some kind of clipping mask with one white menu and one black but I can't figure out how to do this.

EDIT: As my post wasn't clear about what I'm trying to do,I made a gif to explain. Here imagine that the circle is my fixed menu, and the background is my differents pages. When I move the scroll position, we can see that a different color is showing. If we stop the scroll in the middle, the circle si black on the white, and white on the black. [gif here](https://gph.is/g/4zwrlMK)

Comment: Jquery can do this in 3 lines. Why would you not use it?

Comment: I think I didn't express myself well. I'm ok with Jquery, I just can't figure out how to do it :) I don't want my menu to just color change. I want it to be dynamic. If half of it is on the black and the other half is on the white, I want it to be half black/half white

Comment: Then just make the menu background transparent. Black on black and white on white. I’d still use jqiery to change your text color. Your other option would be adding a black stroke to your white text so it shows on both backgrounds without the need for jquery.

Comment: On `section` `active` you can make changes as per your requirement as `fullpage.js` will show particular section active when you scroll

Comment: As I wasn't clear, I added a gif to my post to explain better what I need